# Are ScaLAPACK subroutines 'blocking' in MPI lingo?

Tags: mpi, scalapack

I feel like this is a dumb question, but I really don't know how to google this, since every combination of the words 'ScaLAPACK' and 'block' just bombards you with information about the block-cyclic matrix distribution ScaLAPACK uses. However, what I want to know is whether ScaLAPACK subroutines are generally 'blocking' or 'non-blocking' in MPI lingo, i.e. whether or not they wait to finish on all other processes before they return. Sorry again for the stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ScalaPACK routines are blocking calls. If you wish to use non-blocking scalapack routines, it is still in its infancy, but I would  recommend checking  out the SLITE (https://www.icl.utk.edu/research/slate) project.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Yes, helps indeed! Thank you!